# C# Trying to format datagridview data and pass back through the loop once formatted

Tags: c#, arrays, for-loop, datagridview, converters

I am trying to format my 'Speed' column in order for it to display as a decimal within a data grid that is collecting data from a text file but i'm having no luck. here is the code i'm trying to use:

```
while ((r.Peek() != -1))
{
    string timeS = "";
    string speedS = "";
    string delimeter = "\t";
    string[] Time1;
    allData = r.ReadLine();
    timeS = Dtime.ToString();
    Time1 = timeS.Split(' ');
    timeS = Time1[1];
    string[] rows = allData.Split("\r".ToArray());

    foreach (string row in rows)
    {
        var items = new List<string> { timeS };
        items.AddRange(row.Split(delimeter.ToArray()));
        dataset.Tables[tableName].Rows.Add(items.ToArray());
        speed = Convert.ToDouble(items[2]);
        speed = speed / 10;
        items[2] = speed.ToString();
        Dtime = Dtime.AddSeconds(inter);
    }

    this.dataGridView1.DataSource = dataset.Tables[0].DefaultView;
}
```

The correct data is being collected by 'speed' but is not being displayed correctly in the datagrid and seems to just get overwritten instead of converting the desired column. The data is displayed as follows:
 15:46:20   91  154 70  309 83  6451
.. The column with data '154' should be displayed as '15.4'. Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flip these lines around:

```
dataset.Tables[tableName].Rows.Add(items.ToArray());

speed = Convert.ToDouble(items[2]);
speed = speed / 10;
items[2] = speed.ToString();
```

So that you're changing the values in the `items` array *before* adding it to the table:

```
speed = Convert.ToDouble(items[2]);
speed = speed / 10;
items[2] = speed.ToString();

dataset.Tables[tableName].Rows.Add(items.ToArray());
```

The `Rows.Add()` method calls an internal [`NewRecordFromArray`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Data/System/Data/DataTable.cs,aa156f05a70c905d) method, which uses the individual elements of your array to construct a new record in the `DataTable`. By the time you update the array, it's already been used and your updated values are ignored.

Here's the loop in [`NewRecordFromArray`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Data/System/Data/DataTable.cs,aa156f05a70c905d) where it creates the new record ('value' is the array):

```
for (int index = 0; index < value.Length; ++index)
{
    if (value[index] != null)
        this.columnCollection[index][record] = value[index];
    else
        this.columnCollection[index].Init(record);
}
```

Also, I think juharr was right on about the call to `ToArray()` as well, so there are technically two things happening which prevent your modified values from being saved to the new record.

Comment: I was thinking that the `ToArray` is going to create a copy, but I wouldn't be surprised if the `Add` did too.

Comment: This actually worked, Cheers Grant, always the simple things!

Answer (score 1):

You need to do the changes before putting the values into `dataset`

```
foreach (string row in rows)
{
     var items = new List<string> { timeS };
     items.AddRange(row.Split(delimeter.ToArray()));
     speed = Convert.ToDouble(items[2]);
     speed = speed / 10;
     items[2] = speed.ToString();
     dataset.Tables[tableName].Rows.Add(items.ToArray());
     Dtime = Dtime.AddSeconds(inter);
}
```

The `ToArray` is creating a new array with the current values in your `items` list.  You then change a value in that list, which does not effect the `dataset`.